# Enterprise Architect 10 JavaScript Print to Output Tab

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to learn how to use EA 10 for writing a script to validate my manager's and the team's diagrams in JavaScript, however I want to be able to print the output to a specific tab in EA's output.

How do I do this?

I've created my output tab using:

```
CreateOutputTab("Java Test");
EnsureOutputVisible("Java Test");
```

I want to print into this output tab but don't know how.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried WriteOutput (string Name, string String, long ID)?

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned in his comment, using:

```
WriteOutput(String name, String string, Long id)
```

Works, and prints to the tab you define in the parameters! :)